# 500: internal server error with Jupyter Notebook (nbconvert updated)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am getting a pretty well-documented error when trying to run a Jupyter Notebook from my Mac Monterey 12.3.1, the 500 internal server error.

This appears to be the problem:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'contextfilter' from 'jinja2' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)`

Which, from what I read, is related to some sort of conflict with certain versions of `nbconvert`, so I upgraded it as is often suggested. However, it continues to give me the same error.

Does anyone have any other suggestions? Even if I make a fresh virtual environment and start with completely new package install I continue to get this error. I'm not using Conda, just pip to install packages.

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me by `pip install --upgrade nbconvert`

Comment: This worked for me, but had to do it like `python -m pip install --upgrade nbconvert`